# Why does renaming a file with mv command alter an inode's "change" date & time?

Tags: rename, mv, inode

A file hello.c is renamed to hi.c.
As the output of stat command shows, [change] time stamp has been changed. usually it is changed when inode of file got modified. Why renaming with mv command changes the content of inode and actually which attribute is modified?

```
xyz@linuxPC:~/Documents$ stat hello.c
 File: ‘hello.c’
 Size: 568          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 809h/2057d  Inode: 261889      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xyz)   Gid: ( 1000/ xyz)
Access: 2015-04-22 19:54:34.889330399 +0530
Modify: 2015-04-22 19:54:34.241330427 +0530
Change: 2015-06-21 15:46:45.365465523 +0530
Birth: -
xyz@linuxPC:~/Documents$ mv hello.c hi.c
xyz@linuxPC:~/Documents$ stat hi.c 
 File: ‘hi.c’
 Size: 568          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 809h/2057d  Inode: 261889      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xyz)   Gid: ( 1000/ xyz)
Access: 2015-04-22 19:54:34.889330399 +0530
Modify: 2015-04-22 19:54:34.241330427 +0530
Change: 2015-06-21 15:48:23.361469822 +0530
Birth: -
```

Comment: The inode at top and bottom is 261889. If you mean why is the ctime value changed, then that is because the file's metadata changed - it's what ctime tracks.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. The change timestamp was updated because the file name was changed, but nothing else is changed. What did you expect?

Comment: The inode is the same (see the inode number). Everything is fine. You updated the file info (the name), which updated the "change" time.

Comment: Except OP poses a valid question why would inode's ctime be modified in this case. As was noted, at the end of the day the inode in question has not changed one bit. In fact POSIX ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html ) explicitly states that ctime update here is optional. So the question is why would linux do that.

Answer (score 8):

I got intrigued myself and did a little digging. At first I thought that's some kind of a side effect, e.g. the node gets 2 links and then the original link is deleted and ctime is more of an accident than a deliberate action.

In case it is unclear for someone, the file is represented by an inode which has **nothing** to do with the name. The inode "knows" how many names it got thanks to the hardlink counter, but it has zero clue as to what those names are or in what directories these reside.

With this in place let's take a look at POSIX ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html ):

> Some implementations mark for update the st_ctime field of renamed files and some do not. Applications which make use of the st_ctime field may behave differently with respect to renamed files unless they are designed to allow for either behavior.

And example implementation (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/xfs/xfs_inode.c#L2985):

```
/*
 * We always want to hit the ctime on the source inode.
 *
 * This isn't strictly required by the standards since the source
 * inode isn't really being changed, but old unix file systems did
 * it and some incremental backup programs won't work without it.
 */
xfs_trans_ichgtime(tp, src_ip, XFS_ICHGTIME_CHG);
```

So there.

Answer (score 7):

A long, long time ago, the command

```
mv oldpath newpath
```

was implemented inside `mv.c` as

```
link(oldpath, newpath);
unlink(newpath);
```

Now we have a system call

```
rename(oldpath, newpath);
```

but apparently it still works the same way, inside the kernel. 
This is a conjecture on my part,
but it’s based on the fact that one of the failure modes
for [rename(2)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename+2) is

> **`EMLINK`**
>
>   *oldpath*
>   already has the maximum number of links to it,
>   or ...

and based on the experimental data that you reported
(and that I confirmed on my own system).

### And so...

When *oldpath* gets linked to *newpath*, the inode’s link count goes up by one. 
When *oldpath* gets unlinked, the inode’s link count goes down by one.
Therefore, the inode gets changed
(even though it immediately gets changed back to the way it was before).

---

P.S. It’s interesting to note that the POSIX document lists EMLINK as a possible error return code, but *not* for the case of file-to-file rename.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the file's inode changes so ideally ctime should not change on rename, but it's a convenient way to highlight this file to backup programs telling that that something about the file changed. Thus for backup programs, checking for "ctime newer than last backup time" is the sufficient check to find out *all* files which have changed in any way, since the last backup.