# Does renaming a folder change the timestamp (modification) date of the folder?

Tags: linux, directory

this question may sound silly but does changing the folder name on an Unix system changes the timestamp of the folder as well? I opened Nautilus in GNOME and renamed a folder but the modification date stays the same. Is that normal?

Comment: That's the expected behavior.

Comment: It will not change the timestamp of the renamed folder but it will change the timestamp of the parent directory.

Comment: Counterpoint: [Why does renaming a file with the ``mv`` command alter an inode's “change” date & time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211123/80216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the content of a directory by adding or removing files, then the timestamp will change. If you'd like to see detailed information about a change, you can use `stat`

```
stat file
```

This is why Nautilus is not showing a different timestmap

More info on stat here - https://superuser.com/a/975962

Comment: I was talking about changing the name of the directory (Rename folder) not its content.

Comment: renaming a folder does not change the timestamp of the folder.